# Matplotlib animation not working after pyinstaller

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, pyinstaller, executable

I have this wxpython with some matplotlib plots embedded in it. When i run the code in pycharm it works like a charm, but when i try to make a stand-alone executable the matplotlib graphs show but don't start to plot the data being query. What can i do to see what the problem? I've been trying to figure out but it seems that is out of my knowledge. I have added two images, the first is from pycharm and the second is the executable running. Any other thing needed just ask me.

[image: This is the script running from pycharm.]

[image: This is the script running as a standalone executable.]

Comment: What are your dependencies? (Imports, Data files etc. Everything external to the actual script)

Comment: thanks for the response, actually i have advanced in the project and i solved this already.

Comment: great! Could you add the info in an answer in case it helps someone in the future?